# Find *.res files and work on *.zip files with the same basename

Tags: ant

I have a folder with many `*.zip` files. Some `*.zip` files have a corresponding `*.res` file (= same basename). I want to unzip only the `*.zip` files with a corresponding `*.res` file.

There must be an obvious way to do this in ANT, but I can't get my head around it.

I think [mappedresources](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#mappedresources) might help, but I'm on ANT 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a definitive negative response, but I do not think this is possible to do with standard Ant tasks only.  Some options you might consider are:

- `<script>` if you're willing to accept a dependency on Javascript (or other scripting language)
- `<for>` or `<foreach>` if you're willing to accept a dependency on antcontrib
- Your own custom task.  This is more work, but you can keep your build self-contained by compiling/loading the custom task before doing anything else in your build script.